# Google Play - In App Purchase - Testers are not being told they won't be charged

Tags: testing, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have put two In App Puchases in my Google Play Android app. The testers (not me - you cannot buy your own IAPs) are clicking the buy button and cannot see the line in the purchase sequence that is meant to tell them they will not be billed.

See the picture under the title **Instruct testers to make test purchases** on the page:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing

Instead they see the typical proper purchase sequence where you will be billed.

I have the testers' emails in my Tester List for this release.

**What could I be doing wrong?**

Note: All testers have paypal billing on google play, but I do not think that should matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "I have the testers' emails in my Tester List for this release." you might mean you have added them to the testing track for the app, but still haven't added them as payment testers. Can you confirm you have added them as test account [as described here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#test-purchases-sandbox)

Or your users might be using the wrong accounts. Have you seen the note in that page?

> Note: Test accounts must be on the tester’s Android device. If the device has more than one account, the purchase will be made with the account that downloaded the app. If none of the accounts has downloaded the app, the purchase is made with the first account. Users can confirm the account that is making a purchase by expanding the purchase dialog.

Comment: Thanks once again. You were right, I had missed  a. Use the Developer Console to create license tester accounts: Navigate to Settings > Account details. b. In the License Testing section, add your tester's email addresses to Gmail accounts with testing access field. c. Save your changes. Testers can begin making purchases of your in-app products within 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In your phone go to settings - Apps - Google Play Store and delete data and cache, then open your app again